# Prime Numbers Java - Wheres my mistake

Tags: java

```
public class primzahlen {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(2 % 1);

    calculate_primenumber(10);

}

static void calculate_primenumber(int a) {

    int zahl = 1;
    boolean isprimenumber = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j > 0) {
                // No PrimeNumber
                isprimenumber = false;
            } else {
                // Is PrimeNumber
                isprimenumber = true;
                zahl = i;
                System.out.println(zahl);
            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work.

I want to calculate 10 prime numbers.

But somehow it only prints counts up to 10 3 times and thats it.

I don't know wheres my mistake.

I have 2 for loops. That's how I learned the prime numbers calculation that I have to use 2 for loops for it but it don't work. I thought first it is the % (the rest) but when I do it on paper it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least four things wrong with your code.

First, you have the `%` condition backwards.  If you're testing the number `i`, and you want to see if it has a divisor `j`, then you need to test `i % j == 0`.  If this is true, the number is not prime.  The way you tested it, though, you told it that if `i % j` is **not** zero, then the number is not prime.

Second, when you test to see if something divides `i`, you cannot test 1, and you cannot test `i` itself.  Therefore,

```
 for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
```

should look more like

```
 for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

although it's usually

```
 for (int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
```

since once you get past the square root of `i` you don't need to search any more.

Third: your inner loop sets `isprimenumber` to either `true` or `false` on every iteration.  That isn't right.  If we find a case where `i` has a divisor, we know that `isprimenumber` is `false`, and we should **never** set it to `true` again, for that `i`.  So a loop like this would work:

```
    isprimenumber = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            // No PrimeNumber
            isprimenumber = false;
        } 
            // If it's non-zero, don't set isprimenumber to true, because if we
            // set it to false earlier, then it still should be false! 

    }

    // And wait until we've tested all the j's before we can tell if it's true.
    if (isprimenumber) {
    }
```

You can also put `break` after `isprimenumber = false`, because once we've found a divisor we don't need to keep looking.

```
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            // No PrimeNumber
            isprimenumber = false;
            break;
        }
```

Without the `break`, the loop will go on a few more times but it won't do anything useful.  (But it won't be harmful, either.)

Fourth, you said you want to print 10 primes, but your logic tested all the numbers from 1 to 10, and there aren't 10 primes in that range.  If you want the first 10 primes, where your parameter `a` is 10, you can't stop the loop at `i <= a`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
```

Instead, you'll need to declare another counter to count the number of primes.

```
int count = 0;
```

and when you find a prime and print it:

```
count++;
```

Then you could write your `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; count < a; i++) {
```

and it will stop when the number of primes reaches `a`.

**EDIT:** There's one more error I missed: the code I suggested will find that 1 is a prime number, but technically it isn't (so say the mathematicians).  So you should start at `i = 2`:

```
for (int i = 2; count < a; i++) {
```

Comment: Clever way to take care of counting the number of primes... plus including the optimizations *and* explaining them is great. +1

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I really appreciate it, read it like 3 times to get it in my brain. Would give kudos have to little rep.

Answer (score 1):

#### "I want to check for 10 prime numbers"

When you say

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
```

You are saying "the numbers from 1 to `a`," which in this case is 1 to 10. Thus, you can only check 1 through 10 for primality. `a` is the upper bound you place on the numbers to check for primality.

If you want to get the first 10 prime number instead, you are going to have to use a condition which checks for the number of primes you have discovered (and keep count of that).

#### "It only prints counts up to 10 3 times and thats it"

Your modulus check should be `(i % j == 0)` - this means that `j` evenly divides `i`, and is therefore a factor of `i`. As you stand, you are saying that if any `j` is not a factor of `i`, the number is immediately composite. Not only is this not a correct conclusion, but it jumps the gun on your decision. You should assume it is prime until you can prove it is composite - *then* you can decide early.

One thing to keep in mind is the fact that a number, mod itself, is always 0. The same goes for a number mod 1. So, you will have to make sure you do not compare any `i` with itself or with 1. Change the second `for` loop to stop when `j < i` and to start with `j = 2`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    isprimenumber = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        // check each number less than this one for factors
        if (i % j == 0) {
            // found an even divisor, so the number is composite
            isprimenumber = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isprimenumber) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

You can make other optimizations by noting that `1` is generally not considered a prime number, so you can have your first loop be `for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++)` and also considering that there are no even divisors of a number greater than one half of that number, so you can have your second loop be `for (int j=2; j < i/2; j++)`.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi The modulus check is *certainly* part of the problem.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Having that backwards is still going to cause problems, but sure, I'll give a code example of how the loop should be fixed.

Comment: There's still at least one serious error in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

```
public class Primzahlen {

public static void main(String[] args){

calculate_primenumber(10);

}

static void calculate_primenumber(int a) {

int primesFound = 0;
boolean isprimenumber;


for(int i = 2; primesFound < a; i++){
    isprimenumber = true;
    for(int j = 2; j < i ; j++){
        if(i % j == 0){
            isprimenumber = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isprimenumber){
        primesFound++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

}

}
```

but you can make it more efficient. This is only one way : [klick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score -1):

You must do the true thing on the end of the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j > 0) {
            // No PrimeNumber
            isprimenumber = false;
        } else {
            // Is PrimeNumber
            isprimenumber = true;
        }

    }
    if(isprimenumber)
        System.out.println(i);

}
```

you can only tell its a prime if you tested all numbers.

Comment: This doesn't work because the result is overwritten on every iteration of the inner loop.